HDD Randomly Disconnects After 10-20 Minutes — How to Fix or Recover Data
details:
st2000lm007-1r8174 HDD 2T
ACER nitro 5 laptop
I’m having an issue with my HDD where it randomly disappears after 10-20 minutes of use. It becomes inaccessible until I restart my system, at which point it reappears, only to disappear again after another short period. I’ve noticed there may be some corrupted sections on the disk.
I’m trying to save as much data as possible before it fully dies. My questions are:
Why is the HDD disappearing randomly?
Is it a sign of impending failure or could it be something else like overheating or a connection issue?
What’s the best way to copy or recover data before the drive becomes completely unusable?
Are there any tools or techniques you recommend for recovering data from a failing HDD?
Is there any chance of fixing the corrupted sections and stabilizing the drive, or should I focus on recovering data only?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Windows 11. Disk D so it is only data (no windows).
errors:

The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, has a bad block.


The shadow copies of volume D: were aborted because of an IO failure on volume D:.


A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume D:.
A corruption was found in a file system index structure.  The file
reference number is 0x100000010f4bc.  The name of the file is
"\work\Source.NET\ApplicationsCloud\Web.Portal\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\non_bower_components\kendo\2015.2.624\styles\Office365".
The corrupted index attribute is ":$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".
A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume D:.
The exact nature of the corruption is unknown.  The file system
structures need to be scanned online.


A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume D:.
A corruption was found in a file system index structure.  The file
reference number is 0x100000010f48f.  The name of the file is "".  The corrupted index attribute is
":$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".


The storage optimizer couldn't complete defragmentation on DATA (D:)
because: The dirty bit is set on this volume. (0x89000015)


{Delayed Write Failed} Windows was unable to save all the data for the
file D:\oldphone. The data has been lost. This error may be caused by
a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try
to save this file elsewhere.


Disk 0 has been surprise removed.

CHKDSK /SPOTFIX:
Volume label is DATA.

Examining 0 corruption records ...

0 corruption records processed in 0.1 seconds.

There is no list of previously identified issues associated with this drive.
No further action is required.

And this 
p.s I tried several tools but they do nothing. or not enough time to do it.
p.s.s: There are some jpg files, if I try to open it disk is disconnect

You have given us absolutely no information to even make an educated guess at the failure profile of the device. So it’s impossible for us to tell you why the HDD is disappearing within File Explorer. It’s impossible from the description you provided conclusively conclude if the HDD is overheating although that’s extremely unlikely

"my HDD ... randomly disappears" is your interpretation of what you experience. Instead you need to provide descriptions of the symptoms that you refer to as "* disappearing*". Provide the details of the problem rather than just your summary of "disappearing randomly".

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It could be anything from operating system to a bad cord or connector, to a dying HDD.

Sorry, for not being informative, I do not really know what provide to you. I updated post with some errors from event log.

First, do not run chkdsk or anything like that as it could cause further corruption. Is this an internal or external drive? Does it make any strange clicking noises?

internal in laptop. chkdsk to late. yes, last two weeks I started get some noise, like plastic in fan, really quick, one time in day maximum.
